# SQL Comparing values in two rows

Tags: sql

I have the following data of sales for various categories of items:

```
category       year         salesVolume  
1              2002          45  
1              2003          47  
2              2002          789
2              2003          908
3              2002          333
3              2003          123
41             2002          111
41             2003          90
```

Now I want to compare sales volume in the year 2002 to the year 2003, category wise, 
and write results as:

```
category        salesIncreasing?
1                 TRUE
2                 TRUE
3                 FALSE
41                FALSE
```

Is it possible to do it in SQL. If so please let me know. Actually I am using Impala SQL. Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    a.category, 
    CASE WHEN a.salesVolumes < b.salesVolumes THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END AS salesIncreasing
FROM MyTable a
INNER JOIN MyTable b ON a.category = b.category
WHERE a.year = 2002
AND b.year = 2003
```

The idea is to have a single table as a result that let you compare and project the sales into a new data. In order to do this, you join the table with itself, and you use two restrictions in the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with conditional aggregation as well as using a join:

```
select fd.product,
       sum(case when year = 2002 then SalesVolume end) as sales_2002,
       sum(case when year = 2003 then SalesVolume end) as sales_2003,
       (case when sum(case when year = 2002 then SalesVolume end) is null
             then 'New2003'
             when sum(case when year = 2003 then SalesVolume end) is null
             then 'No2003'
             when sum(case when year = 2002 then SalesVolume end) > sum(case when year = 2003 then SalesVolume end) 
             then 'Decreasing'
             when sum(case when year = 2002 then SalesVolume end) = sum(case when year = 2003 then SalesVolume end) 
             then 'Equal'
             else 'Increasing'
        end) as Direction
from followingdata fd
where year in (2002, 2003)
group by fd.product;
```

The advantage of this approach over a `join` is that it handles *all* products, even those that do not appear in both years.

Comment: Thanks for the code.

Running the above in Impala (hive) SQL produces the following error: ERROR: AnalysisException: select list expression not produced by aggregation output (missing from GROUP BY clause?): fd.product

I am not sure what is the solution.

Comment: @user3282777 . . . Fixed.  I accidentally left out the `group by`.

Comment: Well, I added a Group by clause at the end as: 'group by fd.product' and it solved the problem. Excellent code as it caters to null values in a year. Thanks.